# CubePro 3D Printer

Tags: calibration

How to check leveling of printer bed ? 
What should be ideal values on x,y and z to ensure printer bed is flat and there is no angle between plane of nozzle and plane of printer bed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CubePro printer appears to have a comprehensive leveling system built into the menu. The direct instructions for this process can be found here:
[CubePro Calibration](http://infocenter.3dsystems.com/cubepro/user-guide/maintenance/calibrating-z-gap-and-print-pad-level)

I would suggest that "ideal values" are those created by the calibration process that confirms the necessary settings for a good print.